# Use JAVA multi-line outputs as variables within shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, variables, scripting

My JAVA code output looks like below.

```
    Name="John"
    Age="23"
    Gender="Male"
    Phone="+123 456 789"
    ..
    ..
```

I want to use above java code output as variables within the shell-script without writing any intermediate file. I'm trying to get the variables using below command inside Myscript.sh

```
JAVA_OUTPUT=`java -cp ojdbc6.jar:. javaClassFile args`
echo $JAVA_OUTPUT
```

But I'm unable to set the java output as variables within shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an associative array to store all the key/value pairs:

```
declare -A vars
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    vars[$key]=$value;
done < <(java -cp ojdbc6.jar:. javaClassFile args)
echo "${vars[Name]} is ${vars[Age]}"
# Etc.
```

Or if you change your java program to add quotes around the values with spaces like the phone number one, something like `source <(java -cp ojdbc6.jar:. javaClassFile args)` might work for creating multiple variables.

Comment: I have modified my java code to add quotes for values but source command is not working for declaring variables. And while loop throwing syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: @balachandar Sure you're using bash?

Comment: Yes. I'm using bash env

Comment: @balachandar `source <(your program)` has to work in Bash – according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution), the functionality behind the syntax has been there since at least 1994. Make sure you don't add any extra space character between the "less than" sign and the left parenthesis.